# Cannot mount dislocker-file loop: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, encryption, loop-device

I am trying to mount a bitlocker encrypted drive with dislocker.

Here are the exact commands I ran:

```
sudo dislocker -r -V /dev/sdb7 -u -- /media/bitlocker
sudo mount -r -o loop /media/bitlocker/dislocker-file /media/mount
```

After running the last one, I get

```
mount: /media/mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

---

Edit: I checked the dislocker-file, and the OEM-ID field below has spaces after NTFS. Is it the culprit, and how do I fix it regardless?

```
$ sudo file -s /media/bitlocker/dislocker-file | tr , '\n'
/media/bitlocker/dislocker-file: DOS/MBR boot sector
 code offset 0x52+2
 OEM-ID "NTFS    "
 sectors/cluster 8
 Media descriptor 0xf8
 sectors/track 63
 heads 255
 hidden sectors 63
 dos < 4.0 BootSector (0x80)
 FAT (1Y bit by descriptor); NTFS
 sectors/track 63
 sectors 560084065
 $MFT start cluster 786432
 $MFTMirror start cluster 7680070
 bytes/RecordSegment 2^(-1*246)
 clusters/index block 1
 serial number 0feb8f9cbb8f98307; contains bootstrap NTLDR
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see that you are missing specify the filesystem of your device (this case NTFS).
Let's try with this mounting command:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -r -o loop /media/bitlocker/dislocker-file /media/mount
```

Here are some sample parameters for tag -t:

- exFAT: exFAT-fuse
- NTFS: ntfs-3g

Comment: Thanks, I completely forgot about this question! I assumed mount would auto-detect the fs, as it does for other NTFS drives. Seems like I was close.